# algorithm for a 2-D game

Tags: algorithm

I have an idea for a 2-D game that it contains some monsters attack man and I want to know which algorithm can be used for these monsters and which for the man if I want to make the computer play against himself, and can I use (for example: XNA) to make this game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use BFS to allow your player to explore the world around him and use Dijkstra's algorithm when he knows enough about the world and he wants to get from a given point A to another point B as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If your game is [zero sum game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero%E2%80%93sum_game) [there is a loser and a winner], you might want to concider using [MinMax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) algorithm, which is very common for gaming [it is actually the base of the algorithm that was used by [deep blue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Blue_%28chess_computer%29) to beat Kasparov]

Also, for path finding - you might want to read some about [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) - which is a pretty fast algorithm [usually] for finding shortest path, which might be what you will need. To use it, you will need to model your problem as a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28data_structure%29), and find an [admissible heuristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic). A good example for a possible heuristic which is usually good in a gris is [manhattan distances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)

Answer (score 0):

Google search for "pathfinding algorithms".  I did that and found this tutorial:

http://ai-depot.com/Tutorial/PathFinding.html

In general, this sort of thing is called "Artificial Intelligence" or "AI".  To make a "smart" computer player, you should find a good book or web site with an introduction to AI.

Google search for "game AI tutorial".